# opencv Cross Compiling with cmake

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I am trying to cross compile a c++  project that uses openCV and a camera API for Raspberry Pi but I have the following linker error after the compilation finishes successfully:  **make[2]:  No rule to make target '/opt/vc/lib/libmmal_core.so', needed by 'agv_car'.  Stop.** although the .so file is in an directory that is included in the search directories(see cmake file below) 
CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)


INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES($ENV{HOME}/rpi/rootfs/opt/vc/include)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES($ENV{HOME}/rpi/rootfs/opt/vc/include/interface/vcos/pthreads)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES($ENV{HOME}/rpi/rootfs/opt/vc/include/interface/vmcs_host/linux)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(/home/mihai/rpi/rootfs/opt/vc/lib)


find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
find_package(raspicam REQUIRED)

file(GLOB SOURCE_FILES  src/*.cpp)


add_executable(agv_car ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(agv_car  ${OpenCv_LIBS} ${raspicam_CV_LIBS})
```

And here is the tool chain cmake file:

```
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 1)

# Specify the cross compiler
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER $ENV{HOME}/rpi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER $ENV{HOME}/rpi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++)
SET(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} /home/mihai/rpi/rootfs/usr/local/lib/cmake)


# Where is the target environment
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH $ENV{HOME}/rpi/rootfs)
SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} --sysroot=${CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH}")
SET(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS} --sysroot=${CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH}")
SET(CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS} --sysroot=${CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH}")

# Search for programs only in the build host directories
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)

# Search for libraries and headers only in the target directories
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
```

Any suggestions would be helpful, I have spent some time trying to figure it but without any success. "rpi/rootfs" is the location where I have copied the root file directory of the Raspberry Pi from the SD card.

**EDIT**
 after doing the changes Tsyvarev  suggested  I get the following errors: `

```
In file included from /home/mihai/rpi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/4.8.3/bits/locale_facets.h:39:0,
                 from /home/mihai/rpi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/4.8.3/bits/basic_ios.h:37,
                 from /home/mihai/rpi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/4.8.3/ios:44,
                 from /home/mihai/rpi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/4.8.3/istream:38,
                 from /home/mihai/rpi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/4.8.3/sstream:38,
                 from /home/mihai/rpi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/4.8.3/complex:45,
                 from /home/mihai/rpi/rootfs/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cvstd.inl.hpp:48,
                 from /home/mihai/rpi/rootfs/usr/local/include/opencv2/core.hpp:3217,
                 from /home/mihai/rpi/rootfs/usr/local/include/opencv2/imgproc.hpp:46,
                 from /home/mihai/work/src/main.cpp:1:
/home/mihai/rpi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/4.8.3/cwctype:82:11: error: ‘::wctrans_t’ has not been declared
   using ::wctrans_t;
           ^
/home/mihai/rpi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/4.8.3/cwctype:104:11: error: ‘::wctrans’ has not been declared
   using ::wctrans;
           ^
In file included from /home/mihai/rpi/rootfs/usr/local/include/opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h:46:0,
                 from /home/mihai/rpi/rootfs/usr/local/include/opencv2/imgproc.hpp:4698,
                 from /home/mihai/work/src/main.cpp:1:
/home/mihai/rpi/rootfs/usr/local/include/opencv2/imgproc/types_c.h: In constructor ‘CvMoments::CvMoments(const cv::Moments&)’:
/home/mihai/rpi/rootfs/usr/local/include/opencv2/imgproc/types_c.h:423:62: error: call of overloaded ‘sqrt(double&)’ is ambiguous
         inv_sqrt_m00 = am00 > DBL_EPSILON ? 1./std::sqrt(am00) : 0;
                                                              ^
/home/mihai/rpi/rootfs/usr/local/include/opencv2/imgproc/types_c.h:423:62: note: candidates are:
In file included from /home/mihai/rpi/rootfs/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cvstd.hpp:65:0,
                 from /home/mihai/rpi/rootfs/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/base.hpp:58,
                 from /home/mihai/rpi/rootfs/usr/local/include/opencv2/core.hpp:54,
                 from /home/mihai/rpi/rootfs/usr/local/include/opencv2/imgproc.hpp:46,
                 from /home/mihai/work/src/main.cpp:1:
/home/mihai/rpi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/4.8.3/cmath:482:3: note: float std::sqrt(float)
   sqrt(float __x)
   ^
/home/mihai/rpi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/4.8.3/cmath:486:3: note: long double std::sqrt(long double)
   sqrt(long double __x)
   ^
CMakeFiles/agv_car.dir/build.make:54: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/agv_car.dir/src/main.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/agv_car.dir/src/main.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:60: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/agv_car.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/agv_car.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:76: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is CMake apparently referring to host system files while cross-compiling a Net-SNMP agent despite a proper toolchain file is being used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44559445/why-is-cmake-apparently-referring-to-host-system-files-while-cross-compiling-a-n)

Comment: In short: When specifying sysroot, use *CMAKE_SYSROOT* instead of *CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH*.

Comment: If I do the change you suggested I get the following errors all over the places, from what I see this are some conflicts with the header files from the host computer, on which I am trying to cross compile for Raspberry Pi

Comment: Do not use comments for long description, edit question post instead. Your last comment doesn't note any header outside of sysroot.

Comment: Looks like your toolchain is broken. If you suspect host headers are involved, build the project with `make VERBOSE=1`, so you will see exact compilation lines (with compile flags).

Comment: it still gives the same output with the VERBOSE =1 FLAG also, should I change the tool chain? what do you suggest in this case?

Comment: You may create your own CMake project with single executable, and debug your problems using it. With such simple project `make VERBOSE=1` will definitely work. You may begin with source file which simply `#include <complex>`, and check whether similar error will appear.

Comment: the problem appears only when I link opencv to my project, to compile a simple program works perfectly. I do not get any errors

Comment: only when I replace CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH with CMAKE_SYSROOT I am starting to get the problems for a simple program as well

Comment: dose anyone know how should I fix this Issue?